# string.Format gives me Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me what all is wrong with this snippet.

```
settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = string.format("function(s,e){{ ChainsCombo_BeginCallback(s,e,{0}); }}, gridName)";
```

DevExpress support sent this to me, but it just isn't working

Comment: gridName is a variable that is created a few lines before this code runs. fyi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've missed a few parts in the snippet. It should be something like the following:

```
settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = string.Format("function(s,e){ ChainsCombo_BeginCallback(s,e,{0}); }", gridName);
```

The most likely issue is that you didn't close the string on the `string.Format` call in the correct place and your second argument `gridName` wasn't being applied to the format parameter.